# Why do red Saber and blue Saber look so alike?

Tags: fate-stay-night, fate-extra

On the surface, red Saber (from *Fate/Extra*) and blue Saber (from *Fate/Stay Night*) look almost identical.

Was it ever explained why they look so similar?

What noticeable differences do the two have, aside from their abilities and attire?

[image: The Blue one] [image: The Red One]

Comment: Note that there is a "Saber of Red", who is not at all your "red Saber", but also looks very much like the "blue saber".  In Saber of Red's case, however, the resemblance is very clearly explained.  There's also Saber Lily (a white Saber), Dark Saber (a corrupted version of the blue Saber), and a Ruler who is fairly similar (but not nearly to the extent as either red Saber).  Fate/Hollow Ataraxia also includes images of the twinned Sabers summoned by the Edefelt during the third war, and they are stunningly similar to Blue Saber, as well.  Saber is Type Moon's most popular character, by far.

Comment: hmmm , thats Mordred.

Comment: Blue Saber = King Arthuria , White Saber = Arthuria right after she pulled excalibur, Black Saber = Evil Monarch , Red Saber = Mordred , Ruler = Joan of Arc

Comment: @NamikazeSheena No. Red Saber is Nero, Saber of the Red is Mordred.

Answer (score 4):

Saber is extremely popular character. They are just "milking franchise" with character that looks similar to the original. And by having little different personality, they make sure they gain interest of more people other than fans of original Saber.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to elaborate on their different personalities (saying which character has which personality). I don't know anything about this franchise but have wondered why there are Sabers of different colors too.

Comment: As a non fan of this franchise I agree with this answer. Saber completely carried the show and game, in terms of personality, back story, appearance, etc. The rest of it ranged from uninspired to disappointing compared to its potential. Oblivious to why this succeeded compared to the other permutations of females in various master/slave roles they tried, they resorted to copying their own character. Which to be fair is probably the best the fans should expect out of them. If it goes over well, don't be surprised if we get a green Saber next, who's actually Odysseus or something.

Answer (score 3):

@Templar627 makes an interesting distinction in his answer. Personality wise, the *Fate/Extra* Red Saber is more of a hedonist that does thing overindulgently with much gusto (expressed by her somewhat lewd attire). In the game dialogues and scenes, she is (implied to be) very openly bisexual saying the only things she cares for is what is beautiful ("Beautiful young boys are good. Beautiful young girls are better. My singular preference is beauty!").

Red Saber can be loud and opinionated -- often butting into conversations, throwing around advice, and insulting your enemies as she sees fit. Unlike her blue counterpart, she is vain, boisterous, and arrogant and speaks with all the regal proclamation of an arrogant ruler that is partially divine, not unlike Gilgamesh.

If you consider Blue Saber to be a tsundere, Red Saber would be the complete opposite. She bold (her attire shows off her cleavage and back/behind and legs/leotard/panties) where the other is reserved, proud where the other is humble.

Red Saber seems to be a bit shorter at 150cm tall, compared to the 154cm stature of her Blue counterpart. However Red Saber is bustier (B83/W56/H82) than her Blue counterpart (B73/W53/H76).

[image: Red vs Blue]

In *Fate/Extra Material*, Red Saber's backstory makes mention that her care for diplomacy caused Britannia's relations in Rome to improve during later years, essentially making her the person who built the opportunity for the legend of King Arthur to be born. Perhaps why she Blue Saber looks so similar to Red Saber is because her [legend/archetype was based off Red Saber](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4185/63).

Comment: I thought i read that somewhere, i was going to comment on that i had read that Nero is the basis of Arthur but then i looked at looper's answer and i though that's were i read it from

Comment: what is it that Nero is pointing out with her eyes?

Comment: @Memor-X because her eyes are different?

Comment: but what exactly? i can't see any difference with the eyes

Comment: eyelashes, eye shape.

Answer (score 2):

On the [wiki-page for Red Saber](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Playable_Saber_%28Fate/Extra%29), there is a little excerpt from a Q&A:

> Q: Why are Red Saber and Blue Saber so similar? Are they related?
>   A: They are very different!
>   They are different like Takashi Takeuchi and Arco Wada. Or like buckwheat noodles and udon.
>   The model of King Arthur were said to be a fusion of two individuals, and one of them is the Roman general Artorius. I guess there are some relationships.

Comment: Are there any key differences distinguishes one over the other or are they just different archetypes?

Comment: @Krazer I don't know. I have only watched F/Z and just quoted the wiki-page.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, Red Saber as is much more hot blooded and much less proper, as compared to Normal Saber who is much more sedate and proper. Also, Red Saber is much more haughty and acts less humble than Blue Saber. I don't think that it's ever really explained why they look so similar, but the wiki says they don't have any blood relations.

> Also, they are two different people, Red Saber is Nero while Blue Saber is Arturia.

If you look at the wiki you can see that they are both extremely different despite their superficial similarities.

http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Playable_Saber_(Fate/Extra)
http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Saber_(Fate/stay_night)

Answer (score -1):

On [the wiki page that templar627 posted](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Playable_Saber_%28Fate/Extra%29#Development), under the development subheading it says:

> She was made to look like Saber because they wanted to trick people into thinking they were the same character and surprise them upon actually playing the game.

Comment: I've edited this for formatting, but I'm not sure if this single quote is really significant enough that it should be its own answer. I'll leave that decision up to others though.