# How many character have similar appearance with Saber (Arturia)? And who are they?

Tags: fate-series, nasuverse

There are a lot of version of Saber (Arturia). Some that I know are the original blue Saber, Saber Lily, and Alter Saber.

[image: blue Saber, Saber Lily, Alter Saber and Red Saber] [image: blue Saber, Saber Lily, and Jeanne d'Arc]

I also saw some other version like Sakura Saber and Master Saber.
There are also Saber look alike, Jeanne d'Arc and Red Saber. So how many Arturia version were there and which one are Arturia look alike in Fate Universe or Nasuverse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are plenty of them actually. They're known as [Saberface](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Saberface) or like [MHX said, Arturia Species](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Mysterious_Heroine_X#Profile).

[image: Saberface]
<sub>from  Chibichuki!, Saber 4~8. Left to right: Saber Lion, Saber Lily, Saber, Red Saber, Sakura Saber, Saber of Red, Saber Alter, Master Arturia.</sub>

Among them there are *only* seven of Arturia in Nasuverse. They are Saber, Saber Alter, Saber Lily, Lancer, Lancer Alter, Mysterious Heroine X and Berserker Alter.

## **Arturia Pendragon**

- [**Saber**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Saber_(Fate/stay_night)) and [**Archer**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Saber_(Fate/stay_night)#Swimsuit)

  [image: Blue Saber] [image: Archer]

  Saber : The main source of all Saberface. The usual blue Saber, one of the three main heroines of Fate/Stay Night visual novel. Known as the King of Knights, she is a legendary hero of Britain. She wielded the sword from the stone, Caliburn, but it was destroyed and her weapon now are Excalibur and Avalon.

  Archer : Saber in swimsuit. Saber found her way to the beach and decided to play with water gun and become Archer-class servant.
- [**Saber Alter**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Saber_Alter) and [**Santa Alter (Rider)**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Saber_Alter#Santa_Alter)

  [image: Saber Alter] [image: Santa Alter]

  Saber Alter : Also known as Black Saber. She is dark hero version of Arturia Pendragon. She was corrupted by Angra Mainyu.

  Santa Alter : Holiday-themed Saber Alter, Rider-class. She own a custom-made sleigh and wore santa outfit complete with a bag full of presents.
- [**Saber Lily**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Saber_Lily)

  [image: Saber Lily] [image: Saber Lily]

  Saber Lily or White Saber. She is a younger version of Saber before she obtain Excalibur and Avalon. In this state, she is known as the Knight Princess. Notice that she use similar but different sword than blue Saber. She was Arturia from after she drew out the sword of selection Caliburn, and had just began walking down the path of a king.
- [**Lancer**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Lancer_(Fate/Grand_Order_-_Artoria)) and [**Lancer Alter**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Lancer_(Fate/Grand_Order_-_Artoria_Alter))

  [image: Lancer Saber] [image: Lancer Alter]

  Lancer : Also known as "Goddess Rhongomyniad". She's alternate version of Arturia where she used holy spear Rhongomyniad instead of Excalibur.

  Lancer Alter : Violated by the curse of the Holy Grail. She rejected the Divine Spirit transformation process of Rhongomyniad. She remain known as "Artoria Pendragon" rather than be known as "Goddess Rhongomyniad"
- [**Mysterious Heroine X (Assassin)**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Mysterious_Heroine_X), [**Ultra Heroine Z**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Ultra_Heroine_Z#Ultra_Heroine_Z), [**Berserker Alter**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Berserker_(Fate/Grand_Order_-_MHX_Alter)), and [**MHXX**](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Foreigner_(Fate/Grand_Order_-_MHXX))

  [image: Mysterious Heroine X] [image: Ultra Heroine Z]

  [image: Berserker Alter] [image: MHXX]

  Mysterious Heroine X : Arturia tried to hide her identity as Assassin and tasked herself in eliminating all Saberface heroines. She wore cap to hide her identity and ahoge, although it sticks out of the cap.

  Ultra Heroine Z : Alter version of Mysterious Heroine X who acts as the antagonist of the "Saber Wars" event.

  Berserker Alter : The Anti-Anti-Saber. She's another alter version of Mysterious Heroine X. She use Altereactor to defeat Mysterious Heroine X.

  Mysterious Heroine XX : A version of Mysterious Heroine X from further in the future. She is a Foreigner-class Servant and has taken up a job in the Servant Universe that involves hunting down Foreigners. She wields the variant of Rhongomyniad, a double-ended lance Rhongomyniad LR

## **Arturia look alike**

- [**Red Saber**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Playable_Saber_(Fate/Extra)), [**Nero Bride**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Playable_Saber_(Fate/Extra)#Nero_Bride), and [**Saber Venus**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Playable_Saber_(Fate/Extra)#Saber_Venus)

  [image: Red Saber][image: Bride Nero] [image: Saber Venus]

  Red Saber : Totally unrelated with Arturia, Red Saber is Nero Claudius Caesar Augustus Germanicus, she was the Fifth Roman Emperor. Also known as Emperor of Roses, [she looks awfully similar to Arturia](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4177/2869).

  Nero Bride : Alternate version of Red Saber in Fate/Grand Order. She wield different Noble Phantasm. She looks similar to Saber Lily with this white wedding dress.

  Saber Venus : Alternate version from Fate/Extella through Heroic Spirit Apotheosis. She's the most powerful Servant in Fate/Extella game. She wields Photon Ray.
- [**Saber of Red**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Saber_of_Red) and [**Rider**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Saber_of_Red#Swimsuit)

  [image: Saber of Red] [image: Rider]

  Saber of Red : She is the "son" of Arturia, Mordred, but she is actually female despite being raised as the secret male heir to the throne

  Rider : Unlike Arturia, she decided to take on one of her father's treasure, named "Prydwen". It's both ship and shield. And she decided to use it as surf board
- [**Sakura Saber**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Sakura_Saber) and [**Devil Saber**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Saber)

  [image: Sakura Saber] [image: Sakura Saber] [image: Devil Saber]

  Sakura Saber : Okita Souji. She was the captain of the first unit of the Shinsengumi, a special police force in Kyoto during the late shogunate period. She was one of the best swordsmen of the Shinsengumi. But unlike the historic version, this Okita Souji is a female. She resemble Arturia in a lot of ways.

  Devil Saber : She is a Counter Guardian formed through Sakura Saber's spiritual foundation taking in a Holy Grail filled with Seven Servants.
- [**Ruler**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Ruler_(Fate/Apocrypha)), [**Avenger**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Avenger_(Fate/Grand_Order_-_Joan_Alter)), and [**Joan Alter Lily (Lancer)**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Lancer_(Fate/Grand_Order_-_Joan_Alter_Lily))

  [image: Ruler] [image: Avenger] [image: Joan Lily (Lancer)]

  Ruler : Gilles de Rais mistook Saber for her. She is Jeanne d'Arc, also known as Joan of Arc, the Saint of Orleans. She is considered a heroine of France for her role during the Lancastrian phase of the Hundred Years' War.

  Avenger : She is a creation of the Holy Grail born from Gilles de Rais's wishes shortly after the execution of Joan in 1431.

  Joan Lily : She became young because she drank Gilgamesh's Potion of youth. Named "Joan of Arc Alter Lily", she wore santa outfit.

  [**Gray**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Gray)

  [image: Gray] [image: Gray] [image: Gray]

  Gray is believed to be a distant descendent of Arturia because of her striking resemblance with Saber.
- [**Master Arturia**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Artoria)

  [image: Master Arturia]

  Unlike all other Saber, she's not a heroic spirit, she's a master from the world of Capsule Servant. She wield a katana.

## **Others**

- [**King Arthur (Saber)**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Arthur_Pendragon)

  [image: King Arthur]

  Not exactly Saberface. But he is male version of Arturia. He's a main character of Fate/Prototype.
- [**Saber Lion**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Saber_Lion)

  [image: Saber Lion]

  Not a servant, nor master. She's a parody version of Saber who acts as the mascot for the Fate/tiger colosseum series. Or pet, if you will. She also appear in Carnival Phantasm.

  [**Saber Class Card**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Saber_(Fate/kaleid_liner_PRISMA%E2%98%86ILLYA_-_6HGW))

  [image: Install Miyu] [image: Install Illya]

  From Fate/kaleid liner PRISMA☆ILLYA. Arturia power was installed to Miyu with blue Saber outfit and Illya with Saber Lily outfit. When manifested, Saber takes form as Saber Alter.

  [**Artoria Pendragon**](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Artoria_Pendragon_(Hana_no_Miyako))

  [image: Saber Trap]

  Came from Tsukihime spin-off of Melty Blood, [Hana no Miyako](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=88820), Artoria in this series is a trap.

Comment: I'm not familiar with some of these Saber. Feel free to edit or add some more in case I missed some. I made this community wiki after all

Comment: to add Gray also wields the same spear that Arturia used to kill Modred (and i think it';s the same spear Lancer Arturia uses). i recall reading that it's use it locked only those those related to Arturia